# efficiently convert two or more columns from dataframe into row-wise list of vectors

Tags: r

I have a dataframe like this:

```
capitals <- structure(
  list(
    country = structure(
      c(1L, 3L, 2L),
      .Label = c("france",
                 "germany", "uk"),
      class = "factor"
    ),
    capital = structure(
      3:1,
      .Label = c("berlin",
                 "london", "paris"),
      class = "factor"
    ),
    currency = structure(
      c(1L,
        2L, 1L),
      .Label = c("euro", "pound"),
      class = "factor"
    )
  ),
  class = "data.frame",
  row.names = c(NA, -3L)
)
```

I would like to create a list of vectors, like this

```
list(
  c("france", "paris", "euro"),
  c("germany", "berlin", "euro"),
  c("uk", "london", "pound")
)
```

This gets close to what I want to do, but it generates a list of lists (not a list of vectors) and I'm concerned that it will be slow at scale.

```
temp <- apply(
  X = capitals,
  MARGIN = 1,
  FUN = function(currentrow) {
    return(list(currentrow[['country']], currentrow[['capital']], currentrow[['currency']]))
  }
)
```

Answer (score 2):

a dataframe can be transposed and converted to a list:

```
newList <- data.frame(lapply(capitals, as.character), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
newList = capitals %>% t %>% as.data.frame %>% as.list %>% as.character
```

use `library(magrittr)` to enable the use of pipe operators: `%>%` if you haven't seen them before.

Comment: that's great,  but the list elements are factors. can you do it with character vectors?

Comment: @MarkMiller  after runing it you could use as.character(newList)

Comment: what should I be applying to? All columns in `capitals` are already a characters, not factors.

Comment: @MarkMiller the variables of the initial dataframe as you provided it are factors.

Comment: @MarkMiller i edited my answer to show you how to convert the dataframe to characters and then do the original conversion I suggested.

Comment: Just to let you know, another way to easily convert columns to character would be `capitals[] <- lapply(capitals, as.character)`

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the size of your dataframe, just using coercion may be most efficient (i.e., coercing to a matrix is not fast for very large dataframes):

```
as.list(as.data.frame(t(capitals), stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
$V1
[1] "france" "paris"  "euro"  

$V2
[1] "uk"     "london" "pound" 

$V3
[1] "germany" "berlin"  "euro"
```

Or, if you would like named vectors you could also use:

```
capital_t <- t(capitals)
lapply(seq_len(ncol(capital_t)), function(i) capital_t[, i])

[[1]]
 country  capital currency 
"france"  "paris"   "euro" 

[[2]]
 country  capital currency 
    "uk" "london"  "pound" 

[[3]]
  country   capital  currency 
"germany"  "berlin"    "euro"
```

EDIT: I am confused, the result is a list character vectors. What do you want the output to be?

```
sapply(as.list(as.data.frame(t(capitals), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)), class)
         V1          V2          V3 
"character" "character" "character"
```

Comment: great, but like some other answers, the result is a list of factor vectors. could you change it to character vectors?

Comment: @MarkMiller, just added an edit. I get a list of character vectors. Can you please post how you get a list of factor vectors?

Comment: `as.list(as.data.frame(t(capitals)))`
$V1
 country  capital currency 
  france    paris     euro 
Levels: euro france paris

$V2
 country  capital currency 
      uk   london    pound 
Levels: london pound uk

$V3
 country  capital currency 
 germany   berlin     euro 
Levels: berlin euro germany

`sapply(as.list(as.data.frame(t(capitals))), class)`
      V1       V2       V3 
"factor" "factor" "factor" 
>

Comment: now that I look more carefully, the capitals data frame is factors, too. sorry about that.

Comment: Ahh, I just updated to R 4.0.0 last week (where `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` now by default. I will edit / update

Comment: I was avoiding it, but needed to in order to install a package. It has been fine...until now! Sorry--forgot about it. Hope this helps! Also, even if the original dataframe columns were character, it would still coerce to factor while using `as.data.frame()` (because a matrix is atomic (and character), it would coerce to factor).